# Just how or Just as. Do they mean the same?

Tags: phrase-usage

> This song is completely biblical, just how every song by Hillsong is.

Is it grammatical?

Comment: It would be better as "...just AS every song by Hillsong is."

Answer (score 0):

" just how every song by Hillsong is" is not a correct form

> This song is completely biblical, just as every song by Hillsong is.

would be the moist usual way to express this. Other possibilities would be:

> - This song is completely biblical, exactly as every song by Hillsong is.
> - This song is completely biblical, as every song by Hillsong is.
> - This song is completely biblical, much like every song by Hillsong.
> - This song is completely biblical, just like every other song by Hillsong.